# return a string from an async nodejs function called in bash

Tags: node.js, bash

i'm calling an async nodejs function that uses prompts(https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts)
basically, the user is presented options and after they select one, i want the selection outputted to a variable in bash. I cannot get this to work.  it either hangs, or outputs everything since prompts is a user interface that uses stdout

```
//nodefunc.js

async run() {
  await blahhhh;
  return result; // text string
}

console.log(run());

// bash

x=$(node nodefunc.js)

echo $x
```

Comment: What is output of `node nodefunc.js` and what you want in variable in `X`

Comment: The output will be a string, that I want stored in x.

Comment: try executing code in verbose mode. https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can ensure nothing else in the node script will print to `stdout`, you will need a different approach.

I'd suggest having the node script write to a temporary file, and have the bash script read the output from there.
Something like this perhaps:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const outputString = 'I am output';
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/node_output.txt', outputString);
```

```sh
node nodefunc.js

# Assuming the node script ran succesfully, read the output file
x=$(</tmp/node_output.txt)
echo "$x"

# Optionally, cleanup the tmp file
rm /tmp/node_output.txt
```

Comment: Am I wrong or is everything here happening synchronously?
The question was about returning a value from an async nodejs function and echoing that in bash, no?